# Page Rendering Java Bean Adobe CQ5

Tags: jsp, aem

This is the current working code I have in a JSP file. The code simply accesses a bundles service interface to retrieve and update user information into a MYSQL database. I have read that using scriptlets is bad practice and that using Java Beans is good practice.

My question is how (with some code examples) I can create a TraineesDataRenderer Java bean, that will allow me to stop using scriptlet code to render the database contenet, whilst also using the 'sling.getService' method, that references the TraineeService interface, supplied by my OSGI bundle.

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
<%@ page import= "java.util.Iterator"%>

<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
<body>

   <%-- References an OSGI bundles interface through sling --%>
   <% com.netbuilder.trainees.bundle.TraineesService trainee = sling.getService(com.netbuilder.trainees.bundle.TraineesService.class); %>

   <%-- references method from an OSGI bundle to update database --%>
   <% trainee.updateTraineesData("Ben", "Brown", "ben@mail.com", 1, 1, 1, "999"); %>

   <%-- Reads and displays the data from the database --%>
   <% 
      Iterator<String> iterator = trainee.readTraineesData("all").iterator();
          while (iterator.hasNext()) {    
             out.println(iterator.next());
         }
   %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't provide you with a code example as it would be to much code. There are frameworks from different companies that take care of this:
https://github.com/Cognifide/Slice-CQ56
http://neba.io/userguide.html
Or for later versions from sling directly:
http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html

Comment: Clarification needed. In your Iterator statement. is iterator.next() actually outputting html?

Comment: The iterator is ouputing the a users details, that are stored on a local MySQL database...